# Гугл аналитика, расширенная эл.торговля - порядок отправки данных о шагах чекаута?

Tags: google-analytics

Я честно искал ответ, но оф.документация на эту тему молчит, интернет тоже внятных ответов не дает (везде разбирается только стандартный порядок действий).

Итак:

1. Могу ли я отправить checkout_option для предыдущего шага, а также сheckout с указанием следующего шага - в одном евенте?

Зачем:

Юзер выбирает метод оплаты и жмет "далее", и я хочу отправить опцию для предыдущего шага за одно обращение (при этом сам шаг 2 уже был отправлен вместе с pageview):

```
ga('ec:setAction', 'checkout_option', {'step': 2,'option':paymentName});
ga('ec:setAction', 'checkout', {'step': 3});
ga('send', 'event', 'Checkout')
```

Если так нормально - то идем далее:

2. А могу ли я указать сначала следующий шаг, а потом - опцию для предыдущего? другими словами, пока я не отправил евент - порядок экшенов важен?

Зачем:

Примерно то же самое, что в 1м пункте, но вопрос в том, **должен** ли я соблюдать порядок setAction-ов при этом?

```
ga('ec:setAction', 'checkout', {'step': 3});
ga('ec:setAction', 'checkout_option', {'step': 2,'option':paymentName}); // look, I set it AFTER setting step3
ga('send', 'event', 'Checkout')
```

Ну и для полноты картины:

3. А могу ли я отправить Опцию для шага 2 **после того** как я уже **отправил** данные по шагу 3?

`ga('ec:setAction', 'checkout', {'step': 3});
ga('send', 'event', 'Checkout');
ga('ec:setAction', 'checkout_option', {'step': 2,'option':paymentName}); 
ga('send', 'event', 'Checkout');`

Это уже скорее теоретический вопрос, но вдруг клиент передумал и решил поменять способ оплаты, а сайт позволяет сделать это без явного возврата на предыдущий шаг?

Заранее спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего мой ответ будет уже не актуален, но возможно для кого-то полезен.

Лучше не отправлять `checkout_option` отдельным событием, а скомбинировать `checkout` и `checkout_option` следующим образом:

```
ga('ec:setAction','checkout', {
 'step': 1,
 'option': 'Visa'
});
```

Но, если необходимо отправлять эти экшены раздельно, то:

1. Да, можно отправить `checkout_option` для текущего, а затем сразу `checkout` для следубщего шага. На сколько мне известно, pageview может отправить только один (или только последний экшен) из перечисленных на странице. Все остальные нужно будет передавать через `ga('send', 'event' ... )`. Опять же, не совсем уверен, но вроде бы нужно после каждого экшена добавлять `ga('send', 'event' ... )`, чтобы корректно его отслеживать.
2. Скорее всего порядок экшенов не важен, т.к. это будет аналогично возвращению к предыдущему шагу. Но лучше передавать события экшены последовательно, т.е. checkout -> checkout_option или всё в одном экшене, как написал выше.
3. Да, так сделать можно. В воронку данные попадут так же, как и при переходе на предыдущий шаг. Нужно только не забывать отправлять `ga('send', 'event' ... )`.

Свои ответы основывал на личном опыте разработки под гугл аналитику. Так же будет полезен [вот этот ресурс](http://promincproductions.com/blog/undocumented-lessons-learned-implementing-google-analytics-universal-enhanced-ecommerce/#checkout-vs-checkout-option)

Публикация от начала 2015 года, но всё равно актуально.

Если вдруг кто-то нашёл какие-то неточности или неверное толкование в моём ответе, обязательно пишите :)